# no menu entry for /dev/ttyusb0 failing to upload

Tags: usb, serial-port, arduino

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 Gnome edition. I have a problem with my [Arduino Duemilanove](http://robokits.co.in/shop/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=6&products_id=343) Board. Previously I was using kernel 3.9.2-030902-generic. After I installed kernel 3.10rc6 and I start my arduino IDE I didn't see a serial port /dev/ttyusb0 as before for uploading my code onto the board, Now there is only one /dev/ttyS0. I tried plugging my board in all the usb port but none of them helped in uploading via /dev/ttyS0. I don't know it's actually because of kernel 3.10 but previously everything was working fine. This is the link to [lsusb](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5853225/) and [dmesg](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5853229/) command output after plugging the board.

I finally removed the kernel 3.10 and made the kernel 3.9.2 default. The dmesg remains the same and does show some error in the last lines I tried google out the error but didn't find solution.

Comment: In line 3 it says `Linux 3.9.2 ...`. Are you sure about 3.10?

Comment: sorry @ott I forgot to mention that I removed the kernel 3.10 and made 3.9.2 default.

Answer (score 0):

A guess -- has it switched from ttyUSB0 to ttyACM0? I remember my Arduino boards making that switch but don't remember what caused it.

Comment: no there isn't any ACM0 even only many ttyS*.

Answer (score 0):

Their is a lot of problem appearing with USB port recognition on the 3.10 version of the Linux Kernel. I am not able to detect my mouse using this kernel and lot of people are not able to detect hard drive or stuff. If you can read French [here](http://forums.fedora-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=60387) is a thread with people with that kind of problem.

I'm using fedora but here a link to my [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1194649) with the mouse on Ubuntu. It could be the same kind of thing with your arduino. I didn't find a solution for now.

You have to know that 3.10 is one of the kernel with the more modification added so... I'm under Fedora and the kernel 3.10.5 is created now and it contains the following [modifications](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=454723) maybe it will help when Ubuntu will have the same.